# how use Idea plugin to add project dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing an IDEA plugin, the purpose is to add a dependencies to the project (a local jar) to the project. I use  `ModuleRootModificationUtil.addDependency` but I can only create one library. It cannot allow the project to depend on my jar.

Can I addd the project dependence by modifying the configuration file? Do not use Gradle or Maven, which is the dependency management of IDEA itself

The picture below is what I need to add manually

[image: please check the photo]

Comment: Your current way (`ModuleRootModificationUtil.addDependency`) should be correct. Once you added that jar via that API, your project module should depend on it. Can you add more details about why it doesn't allow your project to depend on your jar?

Comment: Glad you can reply me, yes, I modified my question, please see the picture, the steps in the picture need to be set after I call ModuleRootModificationUtil.addDependency

Comment: Can you create a dependency consisting of multiple JARs?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: `ModuleRootModificationUtil.addDependency` should do this (add the library into this module) otherwise this should be an issue in this API. From your screenshot, this is a Gradle project, in this case, using this API is not the right way here because after reimporting the Gradle, this library would be removed. You need to find a way to add this library in the `build.gradle`.